# If Yom Kippur Katan has to exist, why isn't it ON Rosh Chodesh?

Tags: minhag, yom-kippur, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, rosh-chodesh-new-month, kaparah-atonement

The practice of *Yom Kippur Katan* is held on *erev Rosh Chodesh* (by [some](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55469/who-observes-yom-kippur-katan-and-how)) so that we can maintain the element of *kapparah* [essential](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/forgiveness-on-rosh-chodesh) to *Rosh Chodesh* but not compromise the celebration of the day by injecting a [tension](http://www.chareidi.org/archives5762/korach/oymkpktn.htm) between repentance and celebration.

Why do we avoid this tension? Yom Kippur, itself, has a [dual](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/751475/Mrs._Dena_Block/_Solemnity_or_Celebration_The_Dual_Nature_of_Rosh_Hashanah_and_Yom_Kippur.) [nature](http://newshul.net/multimedia-archive/for-those-who-wonder-or-have-issues-about-yom-kippur-actually-being-a-joyous-holiday/) as does [Tish'a](http://www.torah.org/advanced/nesivosshalom/holiday.html) B'av (in that it is called a [mo'ed](https://torahmitzion.org/learn/tisha-bav-moed/) which might have something to do with the birth of the [moshiach](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/144576/jewish/Order-of-the-Day.htm#footnote1a144576)).

If we have precedent for having a day which has two conflicting moods, why don't we import the *Yom Kippur Katan* aspects to *Rosh Chodesh* itself? Those who say *vidui* before *tachanun* could still say *vidui* at least, even if they omit *tachanun*, itself (as an example of a compromise position).

If one answers that the nature of the *kapparah* on *Rosh Chodesh* is categorically different from that on *Yom Kippur* (as the linked answer above explains) then why do we put traditional *kapparah* prayers such as the [*techinot*](http://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/ask-the-rabbi/q-a-yom-kippur-katan/2003/11/19/) and mini-*neilah* in *mincha* on *Yom Kippur Katan* and expect them to reflect the aspect of *kapparah* referenced in the *musaf* on *Rosh Chodesh*? In fact, if the nature of the *kapparah* is different, why should *Yom Kippur Katan* be related to *Rosh Chodesh* at all? An echo of *Yom Kippur* would not effect the same type of *kapparah* as what *Rosh Chodesh* was supposed to be!

It seems to me that either *Y"KK* addresses the *kapparah* of *Rosh Chodesh* and might as well be on *Rosh Chodesh* at least in part, or it has no relation to the *kapparah* and shouldn't be tethered to *Rosh Chodesh* at all. Does anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: Why not also sit Shiva on YT if we allow for Avelut and Moed together on Tisha b'Av? If some contexts allow for dialectical moods, so should all contexts.

Comment: Shiva on YT is impossible simply because Shiva no longer exists on YT. When it does (such as on Shabbat) we DO keep some aspect of mourning on a holiday.

Comment: Right. And what do we see from that? That if some contexts allow for certain dialectical moods, _it is not the case_ that all contexts should too.

Comment: That we do allow for contradictory moods in other contexts. Is the issue that only R"C and Y"T are called "moed" and this distinguishes between the contradiction on Tisha B'Av and on Rosh Chodesh? Tisha B'Av is called a Mo'ed also. Yes, in some contexts we allow and in others we don't. Why not here?

Comment: And if R"C is a context in which we shouldn't allow, then why keep the text of Musaf which says that an aspect of the day IS kapparah?

Comment: Why `Y"KK` and not `YK"K`?

Comment: @Scimonster I resisted all the way through and got lazy and didn't know which was better. cf "what was wrong with the blue tie?"

Comment: @Danno *Kappara* doesn't imply that you should fast (for instance), as is a common practice on YK"K. There is also *kappara* on Rosh HaShana, yet feasting and some degree of rejoicing is appropriate for the day (see [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20179)) just as it is on Rosh Chodesh ([*Shulchan Aruch* OC 419](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%98)).

Comment: I don't understand your title. "If Yom Kippur Katan has to exist" sounds like you have some reason it shouldn't exist at all. But your question doesn't specify any such reason (nor do I see the relevance of such an idea to your question).

Comment: @Fred I'm not saying one should fast -- my example was vidui. Why is there NOTHING related to kapparah?

Comment: @msh210 it is a minhag not followed by all; some have decided it does not have to exist. If it has to be a "thing", then even for those who hold by it, why isn't it a thing either on R"C or unrelated to it?